# Multiple retrievable instances of an activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app, which takes input from a user (name, phone#, email) and generates a QR code. I used shared preferences to save the data so that the user does not have to fill out the fields every time. Right now, this only works for one person, and I want to add functionality for a second or third person.

Essentially, a main menu, that can open as many instances of the QR Generator as needed, and retrieve already open instances so that you can access the QR Codes of each person when you need it.

I have no idea where to start, so any help would be much appreciated. If you need to see the current code for the QR generator, I can attach that.

Comment: `Right now, this only works for one person` what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @HB. The entirety of the app is just a QR code generator for one person. https://imgur.com/a/qh8Ewu2 is a screen recording of what it looks like. I want to have multiple instances of this same thing, because as you can see, this is the input for one person's name, email and phone

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data in a database instead of sharedpreferences. And it should work smoothly. Database can store a lot of data and that too for multiple people. Which might help. You can store all the data of one person in one single row creating multiple columns for multiple attributes such as name, phone, email.
You can create multiple rows, and hence multiple people can store their data.

Database can used in two ways in android

1. Room persistence (also uses sqlite)
   https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room
2. Raw SQLite database
   https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: That would definitely solve the problem of saving multiple instances, thanks, but do you have some kind of tutorial/example of this?

Comment: Go to android documentation they have the best tutorial for this, at least from what I have  come across.

Comment: You'll have to sqlite database

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Alright thanks, I will check it out. I still need to find a way to get many instances of the generator